# How can you search pronunciations of words on Youtube?

Tags: support, online-resources

I'm not sure this is on-topic, but I'm giving it a shot because it's a useful tool in hearing how different people pronounce words.

There was a site I used to use where I could type in a word into a search box and it would show the results of all the Youtube videos where that word is spoken, with the video loaded just at the relevant point. It obviously works by searching the captions (either the auto-generated or user-generated ones). This should be an easy find, but I can't find it. I'm sure one of you knows the address of the site. I would like to use it to hear people pronounce a word in a way that sounds strange to me, but that nevertheless, apparently, is rather a common pronunciation.

Comment: I think you have just to google the term referring to YouTube..https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT753IT753&hl=it&ei=YcIiXZSmG86zsAfoqJrYAQ&q=pronounciation+of+angel+on+you+tube&oq=pronounciation+of+angel+on+you+tube&gs_l=mobile-gws-wiz-serp.3..30i10.19511.22998..23179...0.0..0.87.762.10......0....1.........0i71.b0woPCg00X0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://youglish.com/search/eczema

I remember the site because I once asked a question about the **different pronunciations** of *eczema* and @Atai Voltaire [posted an answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/236106/44619) that had a link to the site.

Here's another example where you can actually choose which **accent** you want. I chose *hyperbole* in British English:  https://youglish.com/search/hyperbole/uk?

You can also search **phrases** using quotation marks-. In one answer I posted, I used this tool to find instances of ["could've went"](https://youglish.com/search/%22could%27ve%20went%22/null?) For the record, there are just 8 results.

Comment: That's the one. Thank you! Yes, I used it when I heard people saying "long-lived", pronouncing "lived" to rhyme with "dive". Funny I couldn't find it from a search.